# Unable to install JabRef version 5.0

Tags: jabref

[JabRef](https://www.fosshub.com/JabRef.html) bibliography manager was recently updated (March 6, 2020) to version 5.0. For windows system (WIN10 ver. 1909), the update installer file this time was given as `msi` file `JabRef-5.0.msi` rather than the usual `exe` extension `JabRef_windows-x64_4_3_1.exe` used in previous updates.

When trying to install the new update file `JabRef-5.0.msi`, the following error message is displayed

> *There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.*

[image]

When clicking OK and Next, the setup is finished without installing anything.

The following solutions have been tried:

- Empty internet temporary folder
- Update Java to the recent version (jre-8u241-windows-x64)

None of them worked.

Is there any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Hi, please try uninstalling the old JabRef version before and then again the new version. If it does not help, try running it as administrator (right click on the msi)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've already tried that solution. Unsuccessful.

Comment: There is no need to update Java as JabRef 5.0 comes with pre-bundled Java.

Comment: Workaround: Use the portable version. - Just extract the zip file into your Documents folder (or somewhere else)

Comment: An issue was opened about this topic on the developer's website https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/6141. If a solution is obtained, I will update everyone here.

Comment: @Christoph S Thanks. But from Windows Explorer,  there is no option to directly run 'msi' as administrator (i.e. you cannot right click the file and choose run as admin, as in the case with 'exe' files). However, your idea was possible from the command prompt as described in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved by opening the command prompt `cmd` as **administrator**, then running the installer with the command line `msiexec /i "path\to\JabRef-5.0.msi"`